# Change menu background opacity after starting to scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried a lot of code snippets to do this, but nothing worked.

In CSS I used this to make the menu floating on mobile:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
   header#s5_header_area1 {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

It's working, but I want to give the menu a little transparency after I start to scroll down. How can I do this?

Comment: has your question been answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user has scrolled it will apply a class `.menu--alt` to the menu otherwise it will just have the class `.menu`.

Updating the CSS should do what you want. Looing back at your question you will want to edit the styles for `header#s5_header_area1` using javascript - a simple refactor of the example below will do it.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {

  // use document.documentElement for chrome, firefox, ie or opera
  // and document.body for safari since that's where overflow is set in those browsers
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0)
    menu.classList.add("menu--alt");
  else
    menu.classList.remove("menu--alt");

});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 2000px;
  background: pink;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu--alt {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  menu (not clickable) - scroll to see opacity change
</div>

<div class="content">
  hi there
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working for me but I changed the ".menu" to "#s5_header_area1" in the first line. I don't know why. I put the code in the head of the index.php.

Comment: Don't put it in the head, since event listener will be added to null. Think about putting the JavaScript just before the `body` closing tag.